# Winzip command line - Include full path information

Tags: directory, winzip

How do I use winzip command line with include full path information ? I know I can do this under Winzip GUI but how to do it using cmd ? Also, is there a way to zip selected specific folders only ? Thanks

Tried GUI and it is working very slow

Winzip command line doesnt seem to zip selected folders - either parent folders or specific subfolders

I am using winzip 27 command line and this is the syntax I am using:

```
wzzip -a -e0 -k -P -r -yx "C:\Users\source\to\save\zipfile.zip" "C:\example"
```

This stores files and folder timestamps underneath C:\example. But since I have enabled -P -r, I want to store the timestamps of the upper folder, C:\example folder. How can I do that ? Does anyone have suggestions?

Also, how do I specify the path for a mapped network drive? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does anyone have suggestions ?